# Seg. fault while printing a character

Tags: c

Is there any reason why this code doesn't work?

```
char* toString(struct number *this) {

  char *res;

  if (!this) {
    res = malloc(sizeof(char));
    *res = '\0';
    return res;
  }

  */
    other working code 
  */

}
```

I get a "segmentation fault" when I try to print it using a printf:

```
char *s = toString(NULL); 

printf("%s\n", s);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works for me, and I don't see any UB. (And I presume the first `*/` is just a typo, or it wouldn't even compile).

Comment: @Jayram, a memory leak does not cause a seg fault

Comment: It's possible that if you declared your `main` as `void` or `int` and didn't return anything, that could cause it (if compiled as c89)

Comment: Could be that your printf implementation does not like to print NULL strings. What compiler/OS?

Comment: It might be worthwhile running this in a debugger so that you can watch and make sure that everything is working as planed.  Or maybe you have an amateurish printf() implementation (you don't state the platform/C library) which doesn't allow for the possibility of an argument being a properly terminated, but zero-length string?

Comment: probably good to initialize res to `NULL` or move it into the if statement if you don't use it elsewhere. what makes you think the segfault occurs in the code you show? - looks ok.

Comment: Wouldn't returning `NULL` be more sensible in this case? Just wondering.

Comment: You my use valgrind for analysis.

Comment: Does the 2nd snippet know about `toString()`s declaration? Have you have prototyped it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I bet the original source looks something like this:

```
struct number
{
  int i;
}

int main()
{
  char * s = toString(NULL); 

  printf("%s\n", s);

  return 0;
}

char * toString(struct number * this)
{   
  char *res;

  if (!this) {
    res = malloc(sizeof(char));
    *res = '\0';
    return res;
  }

  /*
    other working code 
  */
}
```

If this is the case then add this prototype before `main()`:

```
char * toString(struct number *this);
```

---

**And:** From now on **always** compile with **all** warnings on, to not have this happen again in the future ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The quoted code will crash if `malloc(1)` failed. I don't see any other reason. Please add some more code.

Anyway, just use a debugger (gdb). Let it crash and find the reason ...